# How to change this avd orientation android (Left harware buttons should be at bottom)

Tags: android

[image]How can i change the orientation of avd. ctrl+f12 not working it converts the avd to portrait but my application is in landscape

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl + F9</kbd> [Normal]
- <kbd>Ctrl + F10</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + F11</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + F12</kbd>

Or

Num Off

<kbd>Num 7</kbd> [Portrait]

<kbd>Num 9</kbd> [Landscape]